# How do I resolve PowerShell Set-ADUser Error

Tags: powershell

If its not one thing its another today. Trying to change an attribute on a user from a CSV. I am getting the following error - Set-ADUser : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Identity'. The argument is null.

Here is the code. Odd thing is that I am pretty sure this worked just a couple of weeks ago. Cant figure out what I am missing.

```
Import-csv c:\test.csv | foreach-object {
Set-aduser $_.userPrincipalName -add @{
    extensionattribute15 = "SomethingGoesHere"
    }
}
```

Comment: show some rows of your csv file, with the header

Comment: according to >>> Set-ADUser (ActiveDirectory) | Microsoft Docs — https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/set-aduser?view=win10-ps <<<, you cannot use the UPN for the identity parameter.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey Thanks! I manually added the username to the csv (only used a single name at the moment to test with) used userName as the column name and used `Set-aduser $_.userName` in the code. It did what was expected.

Comment: @nosupport2020 - you are most welcome! glad to help ... and to know that you got things working as needed ... [*grin*]

Answer (score 0):

First:

Analyze the error: it says "Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Identity'. The argument is null."
which means that $_.userPrincipalName is returning null which means that "userPrincipalName" either is not an exact column name from your CSV or it returned a null value which is not accepted

Second:

How to confirm?
open PowerShell ISE and write the following commands :

```
$CSVUsers = Import-csv c:\test.csv 
Foreach ($user in $CSVUsers){
#we will write here next
}
```

Then
return in the commented line "#we will write here next" and write "$user." and wait until the auto complete to find out the correct column name and choose it not to write it completely you will figure out if it makes defferance
Then
Run only the commands to view the $users.prenciplename (as you have choose) to confirm that is the one you need

Third

How to know is one you need ?
here is the -Identity parameters accepted as in reference
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/set-aduser?view=win10-ps

-Identity
Specifies an Active Directory user object by providing one of the following property values. The identifier in parentheses is the LDAP display name for the attribute. The acceptable values for this parameter are:

A distinguished name
A GUID (objectGUID)
A security identifier (objectSid)
A SAM account name (sAMAccountName)